# Animated reveal for 14+ Android

Tags: android, xml, animation, canvas, drawable

I'm tackling the task of an overlaying drawable over a view that animates the drawing of a checkmark as in the following video https://vid.me/MsQj

I don't have a preferred method for doing this but it's just not coming out the way I wanted it to, I tried:

- Two views, each with on side of the checkmark to be revealed with an animation, however I'm stuck at the "revealed with an animation" since I can't use the circular reveal on -21
- Frame by frame animation, this is the easiest but I'd hate to have 60 images for this stupid animation if it can be done programmatically
- Drawing on a custom view canvas

My question would be, is there anything that can make this easier on me, or do I have to tackle it head first and just get on with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a custom View class which contains two lines defined by [ShapeDrawables](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ShapeDrawable.html), one for each leg of the tick. Expose the lengths of these two lines as properties of the class, and then use [Property Animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) to animate the lengths of the lines.
Property Animation is flexible enough to handle pretty complex timing and sequencing of various properties. In this particular case you would probably want to use an [AnimatorSet](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#choreography) to sequence the two line animations so the second starts once the first has finished.

Comment: Seems like a pretty nice approach in fact

Comment: Didn't really use the ShapeDrawables part but used a path that had one of the movements dependent on the value of the length of the property leg1. This has opened so many things up for me, I love you

Comment: Haha, yeah the property animation system is great, and pretty simple to use too!

Answer (score 2):

I ended up developing a custom `View` thanks to @SoundConception suggestion and finding out about `ObjectAnimator` which are very powerful in `Android`. In essence what goes on is we set a width for the first and second line that make the checkmark and using the animator change the value of those properties from 0 to the desired one.

On the setter for the property, we invalidate the `View` to redraw it with the new value and with a little tweaking I made a nice View that while its currently only working for my specific  layout (ie it needs some more work on the offset calculation) it's able to draw an animated checkmark with some stuff that is customizable.

Precisely, you can set the line width, the color, the length and the animation time. And touching the java file, you can change the interpolator and all the rest of the stuff.

Hopefully the code, while not really commented serves as a basis for someone trying something similar.

For example the following code would generate something like [this video](https://vid.me/ylif), although not really because I was testing opacity and thinner lines, but you get my drift.

```
<coop.devtopia.CheckmarkView
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:id="@+id/view"

    app:first_leg_length="50"
    app:second_leg_length="100"
    app:total_duration="1500"
    app:stroke_width="20"
    app:stroke_color="#22000000"/>
```

**[Repository](https://bitbucket.org/juan-cortes/checkmarkview/src/a703e13775fa?at=master)**

**Update 4/2/15**

I've played with this a little further and added dynamic offset calculation (fancy way of saying centering) to the *tick*, meaning we can generate big checkmarks, small checkmarks, skinny or thick, reversed or straight and they will be centered in the view. Can't guarantee the same for checkmarks bigger than the container, they will likely be cropped.

Here are a few of the checkmarks generated for this demonstration, of course the animate as if drawn and the effect can be very pleasing and resource friendly. This turn out to be a pretty interesting subject after all.

[image]

Comment: To whomever decided to downvote this, if you don't give feedback you don't help anyone.